# python database query chinook

Tags: python, database

I've recently started a python assignment which uses the chinook database.
The assignment that I'm stuck on is figuring out which album is listened to most. Then, I need to write print the top 10 results with the name of the album and the artist, and the number of times a track is played on the album.
Also, i need to fit all this into one query.
I honestly have no idea how to do this and stackOverflow is about my last resort.
here's my horrible attempt:

```
#connection
import sqlite3
try:
    db = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/chinook.db')
    print('connection succesful')
except:
    print('connection error')

cur = db.cursor()

query3 = '''
SELECT  t.Name, t.trackId, t.albumId
FROM tracks as t
INNER JOIN invoice_items as i
ON t.trackId = i.trackId
INNER JOIN invoices AS ii
ON i.invoiceId = ii.invoiceId
ORDER BY ii.invoiceId DESC
LIMIT 10
;'''
```

I'm using SQlite to acces my database
and the import module sqlite3
can anyone please help? I'm terrible with databases...

Comment: Your question is about SQL and how to query on it. So you need to provide table schemas that people can help you.

Comment: If it helps, I think this might be the database. https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Do you mean which album has the most purchases? I assume that's what you mean, given that you're joining onto invoices. Looking at the current schema for chinook I can't see anything related to "number of times listened to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to get total album sales, not times listened to, I think this query does the trick.

```
select album.AlbumId, album.Title, artist.Name, count(album.AlbumId) as AlbumBuyTotal from album
inner join track on album.AlbumId = track.AlbumId
inner join invoiceline on track.TrackId = invoiceline.TrackId
inner join artist on album.ArtistId = artist.ArtistId
group by album.AlbumId
order by AlbumBuyTotal desc
limit 10;
```

Have a look at the [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement, as that is key in separating purchased album totals into a respective row.

Same concept can apply with "times listened to" but I can't find any information like that in the database..

Comment: Thank you, you're a genius!